# How to change time format in a csv file from DD:MM:YY HH:MM to YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS. or YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS

Tags: python, csv, datetime, google-bigquery, datetime-format

I'm trying to upload a CSV file to BigQuery, the required data type for the schema field for the date is "DATETIME"

"

bigquery.SchemaField("DATE", "DATETIME", mode="REQUIRED")

"

but in my CSV file, the format is DD:MM:YY HH:MM, and I'm receiving the error of 'Invalid DateTime string "21.03.22 22:02"'. I would appreciate if anyone can help me convert the date format into CSV via python.

Answer (score 0):

```
from dateutil import parser

date = parser.parse("21.03.22 22:02")
```

Output

```
2022-03-21 22:02:00
```

use a parser. If you can use the data in pandas, then you can convert the data in one go using pd.to_datetime.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1, 2, 3],
                   'Data':["21.03.22 22:02", "22.03.22 22:02", "23.03.22 22:02"]})
print(df)
df['Data'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Data'])
print(df)
```

before

```
   A            Data
0  1  21.03.22 22:02
1  2  22.03.22 22:02
2  3  23.03.22 22:02
```

after

```
   A                Data
0  1 2022-03-21 22:02:00
1  2 2022-03-22 22:02:00
2  3 2022-03-23 22:02:00
```

Comment: It worked, thanks. But in my CSV I  have two columns for such date format, one has vale in each column; your code worked on it pretty fine. The other has some null values in some rows and it's not working for the format conversion. The error says "KeyError: 'CancelDATE' During the handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Comment: @OsamaSabir show a few lines where it doesn't work. Better in your question (complete it).

Comment: if there are empty values then you can discard those rows if it is a dataframe:  df.dropna()